# Initialize an static member in an fully specialized class template

Tags: c++, templates

I can't seem to init an static member inside an fully specialized class template!

I'm trying to do the following:

```
template<typename Type>
class X
{
};

template<>
class X<int>
{                                       
    public:

    static int Value;   
}
```

But i can't seem to init the static member, i tried everything like:

```
template<>
int X<int>::Value = 0;
```

It doesn't compile, so any pointers on how to actually do this would be nice ;)

**Edit: the answer beneath is correct but you also need to place the init in the .cpp file and not in the header file.**

Thanks for your time,
Richard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `template<>` while defining `Value` because `template<>` is not allowed in member definition of explicitly specialized class[`X<int>` in this case]. Moreover you are missing a semicolon after `}`

This [works for me](http://ideone.com/aF0Or):

```
template<typename Type>
class X
{
};

template<>
class X<int>
{                                       
    public:

    static int Value;   
};

int X<int>::Value = 0;
```

Comment: "template<> is not allowed in member definition of explicitly specialized class" -- Good to know, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, by removing the template<> and by placing the init in the  .cpp file (which i figured out by your example). I can now compile it. Thanks!